# MYSQL JOIN on multiple tables returning no results

Tags: php, mysql

Well let's see, the query I have is working fine, as soon as a friendpost is done, however. If the user has no friends, no result will be returned, and that's what I am trying to get a hang of...

```
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT m.id, p.byuser, p.`newpost`, p.`id`, p.`postdate`
    FROM users m
    JOIN pinnwand p 
      ON m.id = p.byuser
    JOIN friends f 
      ON f.`userid` = m.id OR f.`friendid` = m.id
    WHERE (f.`userid` = $myId OR f.`friendid`= $myId)
      AND (p.`touser` = p.`byuser` OR p.`touser` = $myId)
      AND p.`publicp` < 3 
      AND p.`typ` = 2
    ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT $limit, 10";
```

I hope somebody can help me, maybe I am just blind for nao...

---

**Edit**
As Steven helped me out quite a lot, maybe somebody finds the last bit missing: It's just showing the posts made for the specific user. Even though as I understand the query it should get the posts made by friends on their pinboard as well? After all the `m`.`id` should get the friendtables value as well, or am I wrong?

---

**Edit 2**
So as I went with the UNION and Subquery Method for now, I still want to describe what the result should look like:

Show: Userposts made whereever, Posts by whomever made on the Userboard, Friendposts made on their own board! Not the posts made by people on friends boards.

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN friends`

Comment: Still no result, and yes there should be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. You need a `LEFT JOIN` on friends.  A `LEFT JOIN` says to return all records from the first table in the join even if there are no results found in the second table in the join.
   You also should the `WHERE` clause conditions relating to `friends` into the `LEFT JOIN` clause, so that the conditions occur at the join.  You should also be using `m.id` wherever possible in your joins instead of `$myId` to eliminate redundancy.
2. Your WHERE clause is too restrictive (redundant conditions).  Always use the simplest set of conditions possible, and put as many as appropriate at the `JOIN` so they are easier to read.

Example (Edited to add posts from friends, as well):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `u`.`id`, `p`.`byuser`, `p`.`newpost`, `p`.`id`, `p`.`postdate`
          FROM `users` AS `u`
          LEFT JOIN `friends` AS `f` 
              ON `f`.`userid` = `u`.`id` 
              OR `f`.`friendid` = `u`.`id`
          JOIN `pinnwand` AS `p` 
              /* This will get all posts made by the user */
              ON `p`.`byuser` = `u`.`id` 
              /* This will get all posts made TO the user by friends */
              OR (`p`.`byuser` IN (`f`.`userid`, `f`.`friendid`)
                  AND `p`.`touser` = `u`.`id`)
          WHERE `u`.`id` = {$myId}
              AND `p`.`publicp` < 3 
              AND `p`.`typ` = 2
          ORDER BY `p`.`id` DESC 
          LIMIT {$limit}, 10";
```

Comment: The Addition gave me the right hint, forgot about that :), thanks -> it's in the "where" where i should search for a solution, thanks.

Comment: Ivan, I made some changes to your where clause, too.  You had too many conditions on user id

Comment: I left the 2 extra conditions as they are but added the m.id =  {$myId}, now it's working fine, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Will check your edited solution as well for performance, thanks a lot you'll get the "answered" anyways :)

Comment: Ivan.  You should get rid of the redundant conditions, as they'll only slow down your query.  Try the answer I provided verbatim.  Also, take a note of the other tweaks I made (e.g. formatting)

Comment: Checked out your solution, and and it's faster thanks a lot!, will go with that one.

Comment: Uh smth still gone wrong in the logic, as I now created a new user and befriended an old one -> I won't get his posts.

Comment: Ah, I see now... you want your messages AND your friends' messages... easy fix.

Comment: :D, nope still not the desired result. I will edit the original post to describe what the final result should look like. Anyways really thanks for your help.

Comment: Another edit to get rid of posts made by others to friends' boards.

Comment: With this I still won't get the friends posts. As I said I got it working with an workaround using union and a subquery, which does exactly what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in the end i ended up using an Union and a subquery... It's probably suboptimal, but if somebody has a good suggestion what to improve, please give me your opinion! Otherwhise I hope that this post will help people with simmilar problems.

```
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`byuser`, `p`.`newpost`, `p`.`id`, `p`.`postdate`
    FROM `pinnwand` AS `p`
    JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`byuser`
    LEFT JOIN `friends` AS `f` ON (`f`.`friendid` = `u`.`id` OR `f`.`userid` = `u`.`id`)
    WHERE (f.userid = {$myId} OR f.friendid = {$myId})
        AND `p`.`publicp` < 3 
        AND `p`.`typ` = 2
        AND `p`.`byuser` <> {$myId}
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`byuser`, `p`.`newpost`, `p`.`id`, `p`.`postdate`
    FROM `pinwand` AS `p`
    JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.id = `p`.`byuser`
        WHERE `u`.`id` = {$myId}
        AND `p`.`publicp` < 3 
        AND `p`.`typ` = 2
    ORDER BY `postdate` DESC
    LIMIT 0,10";
```